# $\int_0^1 x^n \sqrt{1-x^2}$

Tags: calculus

I am trying to solve the indeterminate integral first.By multiplying integrand with $\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ we get

$\int \frac{x^n-x^{n+2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

I then used ostrogradsky method thinking that I would get bunch of zeroes in the places of the coefficients but this isn't the case.

Is there some other way to approach this?
Any tips?

Comment: Will Substitution help?

Comment: This can be solved in terms of $\beta$ function. I don't think you can avoid it. Take $x^2=y$ and you will get something smilar to a $\beta$.

Comment: For odd n I think I could solve it with 1-x^2=u but what if n is even?

Comment: @Marcos Thanks I'll try it

Comment: It seems like you can do $x=\sin t$ and get $\int \sin^n(t)\cos^2(t)\,dt.$ Replacing $\cos^2$ with $1-\sin^2,$ it becomes a question of  $\int  \sin^{k} t\,dt$ for $k=n,n+2.$ This can be done in a number of ways, but the formulas are in terms of a sum of about $k$ terms, or a recursive on $k.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews done it, thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

Under $x^2\to x$ and by using Beta and Gamma functions, one has
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^1 x^n \sqrt{1-x^2}dx&=&\int_0^1 x^{\frac{n-1}{2}} \sqrt{1-x}dx\\
&=&\int_0^1 x^{\frac{n+1}{2}-1} (1-x)^{\frac32-1}dx\\
&=&B(\frac{n+1}{2},\frac32)\\
&=&\frac{\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})\Gamma(\frac32)}{\Gamma(\frac{n+4}{2})}\\
&=&\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma (\frac{n+1}{2})}{4 \Gamma (\frac{n}{2}+2)}
\end{eqnarray}
where
$$ \Gamma(\frac32)=\frac12\Gamma(\frac12)=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

You could try a recurrence method such as:

$$I_n=\int_0^1x^n\sqrt{1-x^2}dx$$

By parts, with $u=x^{n-1}$ and $v'=x((1-x^2)^{\frac12}$
$$\implies u'=(n-1)x^{n-2}$$ and $$v=-\frac13(1-x^2)^{\frac32}$$

$$\implies I_n=\left[-\frac13x^{n-1}(1-x^2)^{\frac32}\right]_0^1+\frac{n-1}{3}\int x^{n-2}(1-x^2)(1-x^2)^{\frac12}dx$$
$$\implies I_n=0+\frac{n-1}{3}\left[I_{n-2}-I_n\right]$$
$$\implies I_n=\frac{n-1}{n+2}I_{n-2}$$

...and take it from there, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$Substitute $u=1-x^2$ to get $x=\sqrt{1-u},\d x=-\frac{1}{2}(1-u)^{-1/2}$ and note that $[0,1]\mapsto[1,0]$ under this transformation: $$\large{\begin{align}\int_0^1 x^n\sqrt{1-x^2}\d x&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1(1-u)^{\frac{1}{2}(n-1)}u^{1/2}\d u\\&=\frac{1}{2}\mathcal{B}\left(\frac{n+1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\right)\\&=\frac{1}{4}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\cdot\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+2\right)}\quad\text{Valid for any real $n\gt0$}\\&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}\cdot\begin{cases}\frac{(k-1/2)(k-3/2)\cdots(1/2)}{(k+1)!}\sqrt{\pi}&n=2k\in\Bbb N\\\frac{(k-1)!}{(k+1/2)(k-1/2)(k-3/2)\cdots(1/2)\sqrt{\pi}}&n+1=2k\in\Bbb N\end{cases}\\&=\begin{cases}\pi\cdot 2^{-\left(\frac{n}{2}+2\right)}\cdot\frac{(n-1)!!}{\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)!}&n\text{ is even}\\2^{\frac{1}{2}\left(n-1\right)}\cdot\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}(n-1)\right)!}{(n+2)!!}&n\text{ is odd}\end{cases}\end{align}}$$

Where used was $x\Gamma(x)=\Gamma(x+1)$, $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}$, and:

$$\int_0^1x^a(1-x)^b\d x=\mathcal{B}(a+1,b+1)=\frac{\Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(b+1)}{\Gamma(a+b+2)}$$

And $\Gamma,\mathcal{B}$ denote the respective [Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) and [Beta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) functions.

I appreciate this looks like a copy of xpaul's answer but I was typing this long beforehand :) I just got into a muddle and spent a while trying to convert the closed Gamma forms into (double) factorial form for odd/even $n$.